# using split, cut and duplicated function to filter data in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like this one i've shown below.

```
date <- strptime(c("2011-09-01 00:00:00","2011-09-01 06:00:00","2011-09-01 12:00:00","2011-09-01 18:00:00","2011-09-02 00:00:00",
"2011-09-02 06:00:00","2011-09-02 12:00:00","2011-09-02 18:00:00","2011-09-03 00:00:00","2011-09-03 06:00:00","2011-09-03 12:00:00",
"2011-09-03 18:00:00","2011-09-04 00:00:00","2011-09-04 06:00:00","2011-09-04 12:00:00","2011-09-04 18:00:00","2011-09-05 00:00:00",
"2011-09-05 06:00:00","2011-09-05 12:00:00","2011-09-05 18:00:00","2011-09-06 00:00:00"), format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

volt <- c(7,8,9,10, 7, 8, 9, 10,  6.1, 11.1,  9.1,  10.1, 7, 8,  9, 10, 6.3, 9.4, 1.3, 19.1, 5.6)

sampV <- data.frame(date,volt)
sampV


               date volt
2011-09-01 00:00:00 7
2011-09-01 06:00:00 8
2011-09-01 12:00:00 9
2011-09-01 18:00:00 10
2011-09-02 00:00:00 7
2011-09-02 06:00:00 8
2011-09-02 12:00:00 9
2011-09-02 18:00:00 10
2011-09-03 00:00:00 6.1
2011-09-03 06:00:00 11.1
2011-09-03 12:00:00 9.1
2011-09-03 18:00:00 10.1
2011-09-04 00:00:00 7
2011-09-04 06:00:00 8
2011-09-04 12:00:00 9
2011-09-04 18:00:00 10
2011-09-05 00:00:00 6.3
2011-09-05 06:00:00 9.4
2011-09-05 12:00:00 1.3
2011-09-05 18:00:00 19.1
2011-09-06 00:00:00 5.6
```

Now i'd like to group the data using the date column **every day** and then check if the resulting groupings in v are duplicated. For instance, the "volt" data for 1st and 2nd Sept are repeated (7,8,9,10).

I have been trying to use this code to split it into the various days but that is as far as i can go.

```
t1 <- strptime("2011-09-01 00:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
t2 <- strptime("2011-09-06 00:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

seqD <- seq(t1,t2, by="day")
ctD <- cut(sampV$date, seqD, labels=F )
spD <- split(sampV$date,ctD)
```

SO my question is, how do you extract those data that have been copied from one day to the next using duplicated function or any function for that matter? I'm just a beginner in R and i'm still learning the ropes so your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you be clearer about what your resulting data set will look like? With respect to the sample data you provided, are you saying you'd like to extract just 9/2, or 9/2, 9/4, and 9/5?

Comment: Oops--I meant 9/2, or 9/2 and 9/4.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, here's one way using just `split` and `duplicated`:

```
days <- format(sampV$date, '%Y%m%d')
filtered <- split(sampV, days)[! duplicated(split(sampV$volt, days))]
do.call(rbind, filtered)

#                            date volt
# 20110901.1  2011-09-01 00:00:00  7.0
# 20110901.2  2011-09-01 06:00:00  8.0
# 20110901.3  2011-09-01 12:00:00  9.0
# 20110901.4  2011-09-01 18:00:00 10.0
# 20110903.9  2011-09-03 00:00:00  6.1
# 20110903.10 2011-09-03 06:00:00 11.1
# 20110903.11 2011-09-03 12:00:00  9.1
# 20110903.12 2011-09-03 18:00:00 10.1
# 20110905.17 2011-09-05 00:00:00  6.3
# 20110905.18 2011-09-05 06:00:00  9.4
# 20110905.19 2011-09-05 12:00:00  1.3
# 20110905.20 2011-09-05 18:00:00 19.1
# 20110906    2011-09-06 00:00:00  5.6
```

Comment: Thanks loads mplourde! Works like a charm. Exactly what i wanted. Sorry for late response though, and for the not so well structured question

Comment: i have a question as regards the code. I have a data set (about 300,000 records), and it sort of creates many lists that really slow down my machine, although its 4core,and 8gb RAM. Could you be knowing why this is happening?